# Join tables in Bigquery where only new strings are updated

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following two tables with data:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ Keyword ║ Category ║ Amount ║  Update  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ dog     ║ Animal   ║      2 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ fish    ║ Animal   ║      4 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ cat     ║ Animal   ║      5 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ bird    ║ Animal   ║      7 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ bike    ║ Other    ║      1 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ rabbit  ║ Animal   ║     11 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╝


╔═════════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ Keyword ║ Category ║ Amount ║  Update  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ lion    ║ Animal   ║      2 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ snake   ║ Animal   ║      9 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ cat     ║ Animal   ║     18 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bird    ║ Animal   ║     13 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bike    ║ Other    ║      1 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bottle  ║ Other    ║     11 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

What SQL query (in BigQuery) will result in the following table?

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ Keyword ║ Category ║ Amount ║  Update  ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ dog     ║ Animal   ║      2 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ fish    ║ Animal   ║      4 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ cat     ║ Animal   ║     18 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bird    ║ Animal   ║     13 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ rabbit  ║ Animal   ║     11 ║ 1/1/2018 ║
║ lion    ║ Animal   ║      2 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ snake   ║ Animal   ║      9 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bike    ║ Other    ║      1 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
║ bottle  ║ Other    ║     11 ║ 1/2/2018 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

Requirements 
- Add new keywords if not yet found in previous table
- If keyword already in first table update only Amount and Date

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t2.*
from t2
union all
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.keyword = t1.keyword);
```

This takes everything from the second table and unmatched rows from the first.

Answer (score 0):

The table C looks like Table B plus records from Table A which doesnt exist in Table B

If you need Table C then create tablec as select * from tableb and then insert into tablec.. or if you just want the data  you can insert into tableb.

```
INSERT
  INTO tableb
    ( SELECT keyword,category,amount, UPDATE
        FROM tablea
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT 'x' FROM tableb WHERE tableb.keyword = tablea.keyword
          )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I made it work:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.t2
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM dataset.t1
WHERE t1.Keyword NOT IN (SELECT Keyword FROM `project.dataset.t2`)
```